# How do WPF themes get loaded?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, themes

WPF controls get their default styles, colors and brushes from a theme (Usually, in PresentationFramework.Aero.dll).

What piece of loads this assembly? And where are the resource dictionary stored?

I have my own WPF custom themes and load them in the Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionary. 
However, this does not work if the WPF themed control is hosted in Windows Forms since Application.Current is null.

Is there a way to do something similar to what WPF does? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the WPF themes in Winforms because they are two different technologies.  There isn't a similar theme mechanism in Winforms natively.  You can use third-party controls that support themes in Winforms.  The most notable of these are the tools from Infragistics and Telerik.

Bottom line answer is no, there isn't.

Comment: I am not asking about Winforms themes but rather WPF themes when hosted in WinForms.

Comment: I believe that this still applies.  The base is Winforms, which means it doesn't have themes.

Comment: Winforms does not have themes but WPF hosted in WinForms does. For example, if you host a WPF button in WinForms, PresentationFramework.Areo _does_ get loaded. My question is who loads it and where do resource dictionary get stored in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try just adding the theme to the control instead of the Application?

```
control.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
control.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resourceDictionary);
```

Comment: The goal of my question is to avoid adding themes to individual controls.

Answer (score 0):

(answering my own question)
The way to load a resource dictionary as a theme is to add it to the list of merged dictionaries of the generic.xaml resource dictionary.

There is no other way to load a resource dictionary as a theme.

This works fine when used from WinForms